# Is there a way to configure the behaviour of cmd + tab to not wait until they get released?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

To best demonstrate the behaviour I'm looking for, just see how Chrome behaves if you have multiple tabs open in the window, and press `control` + `tab`.

So it doesn't wait until you release `control`, it immediately switches the window. Is there a way to get the same in mac while switching between applications with `command` + `tab`?

Comment: You'd lose most of the functionality if you did that.

Comment: If implemented, you would be limited to switching only between the current and last windows.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> cycles through *windows* of the current App immediately.

No need to release the keys to select the window.

Some of the 3rd party apps listed here might get you the same solution for App switching:
https://superuser.com/questions/193922/is-there-any-program-or-way-to-make-mac-os-xs-tab-behave-like-windows-alt-ta